# Can we use same feature file for BDD & TDD?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, bdd

I have to start applying TDD and BDD APPRoach for the first time  with the help of my team so I need some clarifications based on your exeperience:

```
1 - can we share the same feature file for BDD and TDD
```

if yes what plugin to use for that ? we re going to use karma and jasmine for TDD but we still don't know how to link functions with test scenarios

PS : I DON'T get it when people give -1  whithout even writing a helpful answer !! be useful or stay quiet

Comment: TDD,as far as I know, is just another approach to write code with the help of tests. What libraries you are going to use is not a concern related to TDD.

Comment: How is thiw question related to java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BDD and TDD are different. Feature file is a BDD asset and you shouldn't be using that for TDD.

Before starting any development, you start with BDD collaboration and derive scenarios from the requirements as concrete examples by a team’s cross-functional members—mainly the three amigos i.e. Developers, QAs and BA or Product Owner. BDD breaks down the requirement as examples in plain, natural language. The examples explain how the application should work from a customer’s perspective.

Once the team agrees on the scenarios the developer writes code to implement each of those agreed scenarios. When you practice TDD, which you should, the developer either on his own (or with other developers in a pair/mob programming) writes tests for different unit of the functions s(he) implements. Once the tests are written, the developer implements the code for the tests to pass. This approach is called Red, Green, Refactor (RGR). Here is a [great article](https://www.codecademy.com/article/tdd-red-green-refactor) on RGR and how it is done using TDD.

So in summary, you should use both BDD and TDD to improve quality of your product and to reduce time to market. BDD is for the team and helps you derive scenarios which keeps the entire team on the same page and the testing you do at the BDD level is functional testing. Whereas TDD is applied and owned by developers and the test you do at the TDD is unit level (i.e. not functional just checks if the code works as expected and you mock all external interfaces including UI, DB or any external calls). If someone claims Testers/QA should be writing TDD, then they have got TDD completely wrong.

I have also written a very detailed post difference between BDD and TDD in my blog. Here is a link to that article https://blog.nocodebdd.com/bdd-vs-tdd/

We will also be publishing a video about BDD vs TDD in our youtube channel https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCJl6M7o44mGaLX03AP22KTg. There are other videos which explains what BDD is about and how you could roll out in a project which you might find useful